# Run shell commands set in docker-compose yml before container starts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'd like to execute the following commands while/before a docker container is created:

```
mkdir -p /opt/server/nginx_proxy/nginx_vhost/
echo 'return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;' >> /opt/server/nginx_proxy/nginx_vhost/example.com"
```

How do I set this up in a version 3 docker-compose yml?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new docker image with that command baked in. Or you can mount a volume from your host machine

Comment: and then start the script in the mounted volume from the entryscript? ... then I will have to create a new image as well ...